# gar --> sogar oder selbst

Tags: difference

The below is about a quote from Nietzsche's "Also sprach Zarathustra".

Can I exchange gar with "sogar" or "selbst" in the sentence:

> Und wenn sie gar mich rühmen: wie könnte ich wohl auf ihrem Ruhme einschlafen?

Also:

> Und wenn sie sogar mich rühmen: wie könnte ich wohl auf ihrem Ruhme einschlafen?
>   Und wenn sie selbst mich rühmen: wie könnte ich wohl auf ihrem Ruhme einschlafen?

Klingt das richtig?

Comment: Is that sentence a quote or did you you write it yourself? It sounds a bit old-fashioned...

Comment: @Marzipanherz Das ist ein Zitat aus Nietzsches "Also sprach Zarathustra". Da darf das.

Comment: @tofro Dann sollte man das in der Frage ergänzen, zwecks  Vollständigkeit und Kontext :)

Comment: Why at all would someone want to exchange a word in a quote and thus deliberately cause a citation error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is obviously a quotation from Nietzsche's *Also sprach Zarathustra*, thus pretty much archaic today.

> Und wenn sie gar mich rühmen: Wie könnte ich wohl auf *ihrem* Ruhme einschlafen? Ein Stachel-Gürtel ist mir ihr Lob: es kratzt mich noch, wenn ich es von mir tue.

Means: He doesn't want the praise, as he suspects he's being tricked to obligue to invest even more. Some literal translation would go along the lines of:

> Even if you praised me, how could I fall asleep on top of that fame

whereas

> Und wenn sie sogar mich rühmen

would mean "If you praised even me", as *sogar* (and *selbst*, as in your counter-examples) binds to the next possible substantive or predicate, which is definitely something different.

In modern Language, this would translate to something along the lines of

> und wenn sie mich am Ende sogar noch loben würden, wie könnte ich auf diesem Lob wohl ruhig schlafen?

Comment: But how to use sogar and selbst keeping the same meaning? Could I just put it in another position?

Comment: The last example can be shortened to "und wenn sie mich sogar loben würden,..." or "Sogar wenn sie mich loben würden,..." - then "sogar" would not bind so close to "mich"

Comment: But how to do it not changing the sentence too much?

Comment: Want to quote it? - leave it unchanged. Want to change it: - change it. I don't think "Sogar wenn sie mich loben würden,..." changes too much if you don't claim to *quote*".

Comment: weder noch, I wollte bloß wissen, was passiert wenn ich nur das wort "gar" ersetze, und ob der Satz (hier geht es mir gar nicht ums Zitat) noch immer richtig bleibt. Weil für mich das Wort "gar" so gut wie immer als "gar nicht" verwendet wird, und nicht als "selbst".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.

The word *gar* has multiple meanings:

> Kommt essen, das Fleisch ist **gar.**
>   Have lunch, the meat is **cooked.**
>
> Die Milch ist **gar.** Soll ich neue holen? *(only in the south of German sprachraum)*
>   The milk has been **used up.** Should I get new one?
>
> Das ist **gar** nicht wahr.
>   That's not true. *(»gar« is left untranslated, since it is a [modal particle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_modal_particles) here)*
>
> Ihm war **gar** sonderlich zu Mute.  *(oldfashined/outdated)*
>   He felt **very** weird.

And of course your usage which also is outdated and oldfashioned, and similar to the last one:

> Wie kann ich ihnen gram sein, wenn sie **gar** mich reich beschenken.
>   How can I be evil with them, if they give rich **even** to me.

Comment: I would say that *Das ist gar nicht wahr* could be translated as *That is not true at all*.

Comment: I would consider the *used up* meaning as colloquial. Towards Northern regions  typically *alle* is used instead.

Answer (score 1):

Jein.

Ohne den Kontext zu kennen, und um die zumindest heute sperrige Sprache Nietzsches wissend; würde ich den ersten Satz so durchgehen lassen, wenn ausgedrückt werden soll, dass es das Rühmen ist, das hier zur Disposition steht, nicht die Gruppe, das *sie*, das rühmt:

> Und wenn sie sogar mich rühmen: wie könnte ich wohl auf ihrem Ruhme
>   einschlafen?

Jedoch die Alternative verlangt danach, das sebst vorzuziehen, sonst drückte es aus, dass sie keine Avatare senden, zu rühmen, sondern es selbst tun:

> Und selbst wenn sie mich rühmen: wie könnte ich wohl auf ihrem Ruhme einschlafen?

Dadurch kam ich überhaupt auf die Idee, das gleiche Verfahren mit dem *sogar* zu versuchen:

> Und sogar wenn sie mich rühmen: wie könnte ich wohl auf ihrem Ruhme einschlafen?

Dem Nietzscheschen Duktus kommt aber wohl doch die erste Form näher.